# How does Objective-C compare to C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c

I've recently purchased a Mac and use it primarily for C# development under VMWare Fusion. With all the nice Mac applications around I've started thinking about Xcode lurking just an install click away, and learning Objective-C.

The syntax between the two languages looks very different, presumably because Objective-C has its origins in C and C# has its origins in Java/C++. But different syntaxes can be learnt so that should be OK.

My main concern is working with the language and if it will help to produce well-structured, readable and elegant code. I really enjoy features such as LINQ and var in C# and wonder if there are equivalents or better/different features in Objective-C.

**What language features will I miss developing with Objective-C? What features will I gain?**

**Edit:** The framework comparisons are useful and interesting but a *language* comparison are what this question is really asking (partly my fault for originally tagging with `.net`). Presumably both Cocoa and .NET are very rich frameworks in their own right and both have their purpose, one targeting Mac OS X and the other Windows.

Thank you for the well thought out and reasonably balanced viewpoints so far!

Comment: Xcode isn't perfect, but it certainly has lots of powerful and useful features. Disparaging something as "pure evil" without backing it up or providing any context for comparison is FUD that doesn't help anyone. In any case, it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Xcode 3.2 is possibly the best IDE I've ever used, with its elegant breakpoint handling, static analysis, inline error messages and tons of other features. Btw, it's "Xcode" and not "XCode". @Nathan, I really don't see why you need to denigrate Xcode by calling it "pure evil" -- without any justification -- in a discussion about languages.

Comment: One big thing you will gain by using Objective-C is that you will have access to the Cocoa frameworks.  Also, C, C#, Java, and C++ all share a common syntactic heritage.  Objective-C gets its syntax from Smalltalk.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Java and (possibly to a lesser extent) C# get their object semantics from Smalltalk, like Objective-C does, while C++ is more influenced by Simula.

Comment: @Michael, if anything, I'd say that Java and especially C# (with explicit `virtual`) are much closer to Simula than they are to Smalltalk. Smalltalk is dynamically typed and deals with messages. Simula is statically typed and deals with methods. Guess which one Java/C# fall under.

Comment: I should have realized with my earlier comment that the unsubstantiated Xcode hatred is probably due to the C# and .NET tags. I came to the question from the Objective-C tag, so there you go... In all honesty, I prefer the Xcode tools, but there are definitely aspects of VisualStudio that I hope make their way into Xcode. That said, I love for a VisualStudio junkie to show me an equivalent to Instruments or the Xcode Static Analyzer for C#/.NET... :-)

Comment: @Pavel - The interesting part of the language heritage/similarity question is that Java was actually heavily inspired by Objective-C (http://www.virtualschool.edu/objectivec/influenceOnJava.html), and I believe C# is fairly similar, so although they don't use Smalltalk-style messaging or dynamic typing, they're probably from Simula than you might think at first...

Comment: @Nathan—Visual Studio (2010) is what I'd call horrible. It takes forever to load and to start a new project, and the interface is way too cluttered. 

As far as the language goes, Objective-C has mostly been developed by Apple, so it's mutually designed for Cocoa. One of Obj-C's design goals was to make it read like English; Java and C# retain the more C-like convention of using contractions within names that make it seem more like "code."

Comment: C# rules. Period! (15 years experience). Objective-C was ok.... then.
Right now I like coding elegant and easy as possible. .NET -> C# does it all. (LINQ = wow)
Make no mistake.

Comment: You do C# work using VMWare fusion? Just use mono and monodevelop (which is an open-source version of .NET and Visual Studio that works on Mac and Linux. Using Mono you can also create Mac and iPhone applications using C# while also using the .NET library, as well as Cocoa...

Comment: C# is way better than objective-C... C# / java are nice productive languages.. obj-c is ugly and many annoyances... but that is what you are stuck with , in general,.. but you can also use mono for mac or iphone

Comment: @user668039 15 years experience using C#? It was released in 2001!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

No language is perfect for all tasks, and Objective-C is no exception, but there are some very specific niceties. Like using `LINQ` and `var` (for which I'm not aware of a direct replacement), some of these are strictly language-related, and others are framework-related.

(**NOTE:** Just as C# is tightly coupled with .NET, Objective-C is tightly coupled with Cocoa. Hence, some of my points may seem unrelated to Objective-C, but Objective-C without Cocoa is akin to C# without .NET / WPF / LINQ, running under Mono, etc. It's just not the way things are usually done.)

I won't pretend to fully elaborate the differences, pros, and cons, but here are some that jump to mind.

- One of the best parts of Objective-C is the dynamic nature — rather than calling methods, you send messages, which the runtime routes dynamically. Combined (judiciously) with dynamic typing, this can make a lot of powerful patterns simpler or even trivial to implement.
- As a strict superset of C, Objective-C trusts that you know what you're doing. Unlike the managed and/or typesafe approach of languages like C# and Java, Objective-C lets you do what you want and experience the consequences. Obviously this can be dangerous at times, but the fact that the language doesn't actively prevent you from doing most things is quite powerful. (**EDIT:** I should clarify that C# also has "unsafe" features and functionality, but they default behavior is managed code, which you have to explicitly opt out of. By comparison, Java **only** allows for typesafe code, and never exposes raw pointers in the way that C and others do.)
- Categories (adding/modifying methods on a class without subclassing or having access to source) is an awesome double-edged sword. It can vastly simplify inheritance hierarchies and eliminate code, but if you do something strange, the results can sometimes be baffling.
- Cocoa makes creating GUI apps much simpler in many ways, but you do have to wrap your head around the paradigm. MVC design is pervasive in Cocoa, and patterns such as delegates, notifications, and multi-threaded GUI apps are well-suited to Objective-C.
- Cocoa bindings and key-value observing can eliminate tons of glue code, and the Cocoa frameworks leverage this extensively. Objective-C's dynamic dispatch works hand-in-hand with this, so the type of the object doesn't matter as long as it's key-value compliant.
- You will likely miss generics and namespaces, and they have their benefits, but in the Objective-C mindset and paradigm, they would be niceties rather than necessities. (Generics are all about type safety and avoiding casting, but dynamic typing in Objective-C makes this essentially a non-issue. Namespaces would be nice if done well, but it's simple enough to avoid conflicts that the cost arguably outweighs the benefits, especially for legacy code.)
- For concurrency, Blocks (a new language feature in Snow Leopard, and implemented in scores of Cocoa APIs) are extremely useful. A few lines (frequently coupled with Grand Central Dispatch, which is part of libsystem on 10.6) can eliminates significant boilerplate of callback functions, context, etc. (Blocks can also be used in C and C++, and could certainly be added to C#, which would be awesome.) NSOperationQueue is also a very convenient way to add concurrency to your own code, by dispatching either custom NSOperation subclasses or anonymous blocks which GCD automatically executes on one or more different threads for you.

Comment: Technically, C# has all non-type-safe power features that ObjC does: raw pointers, pointer arithmetic, bound-unchecked arrays, unions, `alloca`. It just doesn't make them as readily accessible - you need to opt in explicitly.

Comment: Also, your points on Cocoa are obviously applicable to Cocoa, rather than ObjC (there are other language bindings for Cocoa). It's also not clear what you're comparing Cocoa against - for example, WPF has everything you list as well.

Comment: I simply mention Cocoa because most of the appeal of programming in Objective-C is due to the Cocoa frameworks. Would C# be interesting without .NET and/or WPF? The asker specifically mentioned LINQ, so he's obviously looking beyond the language, to the experience.

Comment: LINQ is a part of C#-the-language in a sense that the language has direct support for LINQ constructs (which makes it so much easier to use in some complicated nesting cases).

Comment: Which is fine. I'm not trying to pick a fight with C#. If I had to write Windows software, that's what I'd use. I'm merely trying to point out similarities and differences between the languages and related tools. You're very obviously more experienced with C#, and I with Objective-C. I appreciate your clarifications, but perhaps more constructive answers and less hair-splitting will be most useful.

Comment: It's not hair-splitting, Quinn. I merely pointed out that what started as a language comparison turned into general discussion of how Cocoa is good at some point in your reply. I would still like to point out that your points on Cocoa are not _comparisons_ - they say "it does X well" - and it may well be the case - but they don't say "it does X better/worse than C#+WPF", which is what the question is broadly about.

Comment: That's mainly because I'm not familiar enough with the C# alternatives. Unlike .NET, it's almost always the case that Cocoa code is Objective-C code, which is why I said it's hair-splitting. (I would imagine that C# people assume .NET and consider environments like Mono the exception rather than the rule, and it's the same on the other side of the fence.) With that in mind, see if I haven't addressed the asker's final question, in bold...

Comment: Regarding new additions to your answer: ObjC blocks are just first-class anonymous functions, right? If so, C# has them (as anonymous delegates and lambdas). Their use specifically in concurrency context is coming in .NET 4.0 - Parallel LINQ. Java has anonymous inner classes, which can serve in that role too, though they don't capture mutable locals, and are extremely verbose for such a construct.

Comment: That's a good question — Blocks are closures, but I don't know how close they are to their C# cousins. All in all, they sound pretty close. (They're certainly not the same as anonymous inner classes in Java.) Blocks capture surrounding scope (including relevant local variables) and are automatically copied to the heap as necessary. They can be treated as similar to anonymous functions, but there are some subtle differences. One of the biggest differences, obviously, is the ability to dispatch blocks with GCD.

Comment: +1 excellent answer Quinn

Comment: I think it's more relevant to compare not just the language but the actual UI framework: Cocoa vs .Net... When it comes to iPhone vs Windows Phone: it's much easier to start on Window Phone 7. However, quite quickly you realise how extensive Cocoa on the iPhone is. Apple's documentation is also outstanding, lots of details and examples.

Answer (score 56):

I've been programming in C, C++ and C# now for over 20 years, first started in 1990.   I have just decided to have a look at the iPhone development and Xcode and Objective-C.  Oh my goodness... all the complaints about Microsoft I take back, I realise now how bad things code have been.  Objective-C is over complex compared to what C# does. I have been spoilt with C# and now I appreciate all the hard work Microsoft have put in.   Just reading Objective-C with method invokes is difficult to read.  C# is elegant in this.   That is just my opinion, I hoped that the Apple development language was a good as the Apple products, but dear me, they have a lot to learn from Microsoft.  There is no question C#.NET application I can get an application up and running many times faster than XCode Objective-C.  Apple should certainly take a leaf out of Microsoft's book here and then we'd have the perfect environment. :-)

Comment: Even though you've glanced at an iPhone dev book you are still able to create an app faster on a platform you have 20 years experience on? AMAZING

Comment: I'm having the exact same experience as Waz. I'm also much more grateful for the work Microsoft has put in C# and the development tools such as Visual Studio, after I've started learning Objective C.

Comment: That was my experience as well while studying objective-c, overcomplexity compared to c#. @alexy13 What part of the c and c++ from the original message have you missed? Having decades of experience in one family of languages helps a LOT to evaluate how hard is it to do the same job with another language from the same family.

Comment: I recently started doing iPhone development after 15+ years of MS development and found objective c fine after the initial learning curve. But as for getting an app up and running, Xcode has been a positive experience for me. The Mvc approach to development feels far more mature when say compared to WPF's MVVM, which in big development teams has been the cause of too many technical holy wars.

Comment: @santos - We develop large WPF MVVM applications at our company and we all feel that it is, by far, the best pattern to build reliable and robust software in large teams if well applied.

Comment: how is this top answer? it isn't a concise answer, just a clearly biased opinion of some language he learnt overnight vs a language he has been using over 20 years...obviously you will not be as proficient on the new language

Comment: `"Just reading Objective-C with method invokes is difficult to read"` - here is just *one* very **subjective** argument that mentioned here as cons of Obj-C. All other is just disputable rhetoric.

Comment: @Heavy_Bullets OP hasn't been using C# for over twenty years; it hasn't even been out that long. Look at the first two languages he mentions: those are the ancestors of Obj-C. Hell, all C code *is* valid Obj-C.

Comment: -1 I have 15 years of C/C++/C#/Obj-C experience and I find you accusations not very well founded. They lack technical merit and very subjective - not _ad rem_, so to speak. Programming languages are tools, we just need to find the right ones for the job.

Comment: -1 All opinions. Zero facts.

Answer (score 47):

No technical review here, but I just find Objective-C much less readable.
Given the example Cinder6 gave you:

C#

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("xyzzy");                  // takes only strings
strings.Add(15);                       // compiler error
string x = strings[0];                 // guaranteed to be a string
strings.RemoveAt(0);                   // or non-existant (yielding an exception)
```

Objective-C

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
[strings addObject:@"xyzzy"];
[strings addObject:@15];
NSString *x = strings[0];
[strings removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

It looks awful. I even tried reading 2 books on it, they lost me early on,
and normally I don't get that with programming books / languages.

I'm glad we have Mono for Mac OS, because if I'd had to rely on Apple
to give me a good development environment...

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the 1st line should end with `[NSMutableArray array]` instead (he's leaking memory) and the 4th line should start with `NSString* x` or `id x` (compile error)... Yes, Objective-C lacks generics (I honestly don't miss them), you don't index objects with array syntax, and the APIs are generally more verbose. To-may-to, to-mah-to. It really comes down to what you prefer to see. (You could write the same code in C++ STL and I'd think it was hideous.) To me, readable code often means the text of the code tells you what it's doing, and thus the Objective-C code is preferable.

Comment: I don't really find anything wrong with syntax as such - the main reason why it _feels_ less readable is because 1) it's unfamiliar to everyone coming from C background, and 2) it is used in the middle of plain C constructs, where it looks alien. On the other hand, Smalltalkish named-parameters-as-part-of-method-name actually make calls more understandable from the get go. In fact, your C# code sample demonstrates this well - it won't compile, because `List<T>.Remove` takes a _string_ as an argument, and removes first occurenceof that string. To remove by index, you need `RemoveAt`.

Comment: ... whereas ObjC version with `removeObjectAtIndex:`, while more verbose, is also unambiguous as to what it does.

Comment: Excellent points, Pavel. Also, the inconsistency between `strings[0]` and `strings.RemoveAt(0)` detracts from the clarity, at least for me. (Also, it always bugs me when method names begin with a capital letter... I know it's a minor niggle, but it's just weird.)

Comment: On the other hand, `strings[0]` is consistent with plain arrays, and can be used on the left side of the assignment operator.

Comment: True enough. Personal preference again, but I would hate syntax that masks methods with array notation. Perhaps that's because I also use plain C arrays on occasion, and mixing notation would harm code comprehension more than it helps.

Comment: I would like to note, none of the code samples are mine, they are taken from the page someone linked to earlier :p

Comment: With modern Objective-C, this would be:NSMutableArray *strings = @[]; [strings addObject:@15]; NSString *x = strings[0]; etc...

Comment: the power of objective C grows in methods with multiple arguments.. oh god how i hate this kind of thing in c# this.doSomething(a,b,c,d,e,g)  and having to check always what the hell i'm supposed to fit in what space...  i much better like  [self doSomethingWith:a withColor:b alpha:c rotation:d scale:e optionalFlags:g]

Comment: @Heavy_Bullets isn't that the same as named parameters in c# or is it different in Objective-C?

Comment: is not exactly the same but similar, objective c has this on the method name level and c# has it on the argument level (thus passing extra arguments also and affecting processing time),  objective - c doesn't have this giant overhead. Refer to this for some tests of named parameters http://www.dotnetperls.com/named-parameters

Comment: Interesting read, thnx

Comment: If you need to know something is a string, make your own mutable array class that only contains strings. You can use NSArray internally.

Comment: -1 people in general tend to avoid what's different from their habits/knowledge, so ditching a programming language solely on its so called "readability" is not well founded. Programming language is a tool.

Comment: In my case, as for many people, readability of "the tool" affects my productivity. I'm comfortable and productive with many languages Objective-C however, has never been one of them and that's not because  lack of trying. But again, at the end of the day it's all about personal preference. Unlike 20 years ago, you are not forced to use language X in order to target platform Y. You pick what suits you best.

Answer (score 17):

Manual memory management is something beginners to Objective-C seems to have most problem with, mostly because they think it is more complex than it is.

Objective-C and Cocoa by extension relies on conventions over enforcement; know and follow a very small set of rules and you get a lot for free by the dynamic run-time in return.

The not 100% true rule, but good enough for everyday is:

- Every call to `alloc` should be matched with a `release` at the end of the current scope.
- If the return value for your method has been obtained by `alloc` then it should be returned by `return [value autorelease];` instead of being matched by a `release`.
- Use properties, and there is no rule three.

The longer explanation follows.

Memory management is based on ownership; **only** the owner of an object instance should ever release the object, **everybody** else should always do nothing. This mean that in 95% of all code you treat Objective-C as if it was garbage collected.

So what about the other 5%? You have three methods to look out for, any object instance received from these method are owned by the current *method scope*:

- `alloc`
- Any method beginning with the word *new*, such as `new` or `newService`.
- Any method containing the word copy, such as `copy` and `mutableCopy`.

The method have three possible options as of what to do with it's owned object instances before it exits:

- Release it using `release` if it is no longer needed.
- Give ownership to the a field *(instance variable)*, or a global variable by simply assigning it.
- Relinquish ownership but give someone else a chance to take ownership before the instance goes away by calling `autorelease`.

So when should you pro-actively take ownership by calling `retain`? Two cases:

- When assigning fields in your initializers.
- When manually implementing setter method.

Comment: +1 Excellent summary. Sounds very similar to when I learnt C years ago.

Comment: Just to clarify, garbage-collection is fully supported for Objective-C  on the Mac, and one does not need to do any manual memory management. Manual memory management is only required in iOS.

Comment: Still, it's good to learn the basics of memory management, if only to improve performance when you need it (don't have to run garbage collection).

Comment: iOS 5 introduced ARC, removing the need to manually having to released allocated object. But it's still nowhere as easy as C#. You have to keep in mind that Objective-C is over 20 years old, and it has kept some of the requirements of languages back in those days: that is knowing when to allocation and when to free/release memory. C# has removed all of this for you. Having said that, Cocoa has a lot of APIs that are yet to be as accessible in Windows Phone. Such as gestures, far more controls when it comes to UI events etc...

Answer (score 11):

Sure, if everything you saw in your life is Objective C, then its syntax looks like the only possible. We could call you a "programming virgin".

But since lots of code is written in C, C++, Java, JavaScript, Pascal and other languages, you'll see that ObjectiveC is different from all of them, but not in a good way. Did they have a reason for this? Let's see other popular languages:

C++ added a lot extras to C, but it changed the original syntax only as much as needed.

C# added a lot extras compared to C++ but it changed only things that were ugly in C++ (like removing the "::" from the interface).

Java changed a lot of things, but it kept the familiar syntax except in parts where the change was needed.

JavaScript is a completely dynamic language that can do many things ObjectiveC can't. Still, its creators didn't invent a new way of calling methods and passing parameters just to be different from the rest of the world.

Visual Basic can pass parameters out of order, just like ObjectiveC. You can name the parameters, but you can also pass them the regular way. Whatever you use, it's normal comma-delimited way that everyone understands. Comma is the usual delimiter, not just in programming languages, but in books, newspapers, and written language in general.

Object Pascal has a different syntax than C, but its syntax is actually EASIER to read for the programmer (maybe not to the computer, but who cares what computer thinks). So maybe they digressed, but at least their result is better.

Python has a different syntax, which is even easier to read (for humans) than Pascal. So when they changed it, making it different, at least they made it better for us programmers.

And then we have ObjectiveC. Adding some improvements to C, but inventing its own interface syntax, method calling, parameter passing and what not. I wonder why didn't they swap + and - so that plus subtracts two numbers. It would have been even cooler.

Steve Jobs screwed up by supporting ObjectiveC. Of course he can't support C#, which is better, but belongs to his worst competitor. So this is a political decision, not a practical one. Technology always suffers when tech decisions are made for political reasons. He should lead the company, which he does good, and leave programming matters to real experts.

I'm sure there would be even more apps for iPhone if he decided to write iOS and support libraries in any other language than ObjectiveC. To everyone except die-hard fans, virgin programmers and Steve Jobs, ObjectiveC looks ridiculous, ugly and repulsive.

Comment: the last 2 paragraph sum it all

Comment: Oh yeah sure the syntax looks ridiculous but the gem of the Objective-C language is that it has almost the easiest to use reflection of all languages and some really brilliant runtime features that makes several paradigms almost trivial to implement. For example when using Objective-C I never need to mind which linear table to use - linked list or vector or whatever that is - just `NSArray` and it handles the selection of the best algorithm based on the machine and the nature of the data.

Comment: I entered my fist job as a (virgin) programmer implementing iOS-App user interfaces in Objective-C. All I want for now (after 3 years) is to exit that lonely 'island' and to learn something more platform-independent and therefore more seminal. Also to get to learn if other frameworks are also updated so quickly - and buggy. Hey! New Feature! - *Crash*... Hope the (german) job center spends some money for me on tutorials in Java and/or C++/C# as I no longer want to develop for Apple sh*t.

Answer (score 5):

One thing I love about objective-c is that the object system is based on messages, it lets you do really nice things you couldn't do in C# (at least not until they support the dynamic keyword!).

Another great thing about writing cocoa apps is Interface Builder, it's a lot nicer than the forms designer in Visual Studio.

The things about obj-c that annoy me (as a C# developer) are the fact that you have to manage your own memory (there's garbage collection, but that doesn't work on the iPhone) and that it can be very verbose because of the selector syntax and all the [ ].

Comment: `dynamic` will only get you halfway - implementing a true dynamic object, even with trivial things such as message delegation, is tedious even in C# 4.0. On the other hand, the price for flexibility true dynamic message passing a la ObjC is lost type safety.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Objective-C allows for opt-in static typing, which does provide a much greater degree of type safety. Some people prefer compile-time checking, others prefer runtime checking. The nice thing (in both languages) is that the choice need not be absolute.

Comment: Windows Forms designer is not so great, but if you are able to use WPF (as of .NET 3.0) Expression Blend is hard to beat...

Comment: You can do a lot of this with `System.Reflection` combined with extensions in C# 3.0, you can call any method you find, but is not true message passing, it will look like `obj.PassMessage("function_name", params object[] args);` for better message passing integrated into language, method missing callable on normal object would be needed.

Answer (score 4):

As a programmer just getting started with Objective-C for iPhone, coming from C# 4.0, I'm missing lambda expressions, and in particular, Linq-to-XML.  The lambda expressions are C#-specific, while the Linq-to-XML is really more of a .NET vs. Cocoa contrast.  In a sample app I was writing, I had some XML in a string.  I wanted to parse the elements of that XML into a collection of objects.

To accomplish this in Objective-C/Cocoa, I had to use the [NSXmlParser class](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This class relies on another object which implements the [NSXMLParserDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate) protocol with methods that are called (read: messages sent) when an element open tag is read, when some data is read (usually inside the element), and when some element end tag is read.  You have to keep track of the parsing status and state.  And I honestly have no idea what happens if the XML is invalid.  It's great for getting down to the details and optimize performance, but oh man, that's a whole lot of code.

By contrast, here's the code in C#:

```
using System.Linq.Xml;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlString);
IEnumerable<MyCustomObject> objects = doc.Descendants().Select(
         d => new MyCustomObject{ Name = d.Value});
```

And that's it, you've got a collection of custom objects drawn from XML.  If you wanted to filter those elements by value, or only to those that contain a specific attribute, or if you just wanted the first 5, or to skip the first 1 and get the next 3, or just find out if any elements were returned... BAM, all right there in the same line of code.

There are many open-source classes that make this processing a lot easier in Objective-C, so that does much of the heavy lifting.  It's just not this built in.

*NOTE: I didn't actually compile the code above, it's just meant as an example to illustrate the relative lack of verbosity required by C#.

Comment: Important to not here, though, that there isn't so much a "lack of verbosity" on the part of C# in this comparison, only that the verbosity is contained in the .net framework classes you are using to parse your XML. If you examine the code within those, you are likely to find a good deal more C# code, possibly even more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

Probably most important difference is memory management.  With C# you get garbage collection, by virtue of it being a CLR based language.  With Objective-C you need to manage memory yourself.

If you're coming from a C# background (or any modern language for that matter), moving to a language without automatic memory management will be really painful, as you will spend a lot of your coding time on properly managing memory (and debugging as well).

Comment: ObjC has tracing garbage collection these days. On the other hand, C# lets you manage memory yourself if you want (thanks to raw pointers).

Comment: I don't find manual memory management in Objective-C (in the context of Apple's frameworks) to be a much of a burden: the retain/release/autorelease cycle is much less cumbersome than "traditional" memory management in C and C++.

Comment: This just isn't true DSO - even on a non-garbage-collection environment like iPhone, the retain/release and autorelease stuff takes about 10 minutes to learn and then its no a problem.  I've found a lot of C#-ers that like to exaggerate the challenges of memory management.  It's almost like they fear they'd start liking obj-c too much otherwise... ;)

Comment: The basics of manual memory management isn't hard. But it can get complicated real quick when you start passing allocated objects around and need to deal with complex object graphs, because you need to carefully follow rules as who is responsible for freeing and when. Reference counting implementations make it somewhat easier, except you need to deal with cycles in object graphs... compared to C#, all of this IMO is a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty good article comparing the two languages:
http://www.coderetard.com/2008/03/16/c-vs-objective-c/

Comment: It's a pity the page claims to be in UTF-8 but has all sorts of nasty replacements for apostrophes and quote marks. I think his text uses "curvy" quotes, but they sure garble the code...

Comment: they appear to have stolen their intro whole hog, but even the source article has their code munged.  neither is a particularly great article.

Answer (score -2):

Other than the paradigm difference between the 2 languages, there's not a lot of difference.  As much as I hate to say it, you can do the same kind of things (probably not as easily) with .NET and C# as you can with Objective-C and Cocoa. As of Leopard, Objective-C 2.0 has garbage collection, so you don't *have* to manage memory yourself unless you want to (code compatibility with older Macs and iPhone apps are 2 reasons to want to).

As far as structured, readable code is concerned, much of the burden there lies with the programmer, as with any other language.  However, I find that the message passing paradigm lends itself well to readable code provided you name your functions/methods appropriately (again, just like any other language).

I'll be the first to admit that I'm not very familiar with C# or .NET.  But the reasons Quinn listed above are quite a few reasons that I don't care to become so.

Answer (score -3):

The method calls used in obj-c make for easily read code, in my opinion much more elegant than c# and obj-c is built on top of c so all c code should work fine in obj-c. The big seller for me though is that obj-c is an open standard so you can find compilers for any system.

Comment: ISO C# is also an open standard. Also, so far as I know, the only ObjC compiler in existence is gcc.

Comment: @Pavel: There's also the Portable Object Compiler (http://users.telenet.be/stes/compiler.html) and clang.

Comment: Actually, GCC is no longer the only compiler — Clang and LLVM are a pair of technologies designed and developed to replace GCC and do things it never could, including JIT compilation. This is at the core of OpenCL in Snow Leopard. They're also extensible to other languages, and are worth checking out.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't consider portability to be a pro of Objective-C. Rather, the strengths are more along the lines of rapid development and reduced volume of code to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake on compiler availability. Well, portability is technically there anyway - I can use MinGW/ObjC on Win32 just fine, for example - in that sense it's just as portable as gcc itself is. Of course, the libraries won't be there (though... is there GnuStep/Win32?), but this situation isn't really much worse than what we have with Mono; so on the whole, I'd say that portability isn't a strong point for either side.

Comment: C# can be compiled with the open source Mono project.